# Does a BitTorrent transmission continue when a laptop suspends?

Tags: suspend

In Windows, while I lock the screen, the download files, still downloads 
in [µTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9CTorrent). But, if I close the lid (probably it'll get suspended), will the download complete?

Comment: no the computers goes to suspend as default (this can be changed), and your sessions is saved into your RAM. So everything is stopped until you wake it again. The same happens to me in Windows. and the same goes for lock screen in Ubuntu/windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you suspend, the download pauses until you un-suspend. However, you can still lock the screen and leave the computer running. Press Ctrl + Alt + L all at the same time.